# Redis Node LPUSH command doesn't resolve

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have an issue with `lpush` command. It wouldn't resolve, wouldn't error and doesn't push to the list either.

The following is the code:

```
    redisClient.brpop('c_list_api_' + currentDate, 0, (err, reply) => {

        if (!err) {
            console.log('//got a record at', 'c_list_api_' + currentDate);

            
            var rawLogElements = reply[1].split(";");
            redisClient.lpush('c_list_processing_' + currentDate, reply[1], (err, reply) => {
// This never executes
                console.log('c_list_processing_' + currentDate , reply);
                console.log('c_list_processing_' + currentDate , err);

   //neither i get err, nor a reply... execution gets stuck here
            });

        }
        else {
            console.log('err', err);
            console.log('reply', reply);
        }
    })
```

The code inside the lpush never gets executed. What could be the issue? The earlier `brpop` works fine, means to say the `redisClient` is connected. There is no memory issue, quite a bit of memory is free.